# Can we identify Paul Benacerraf in these photos

Tags: mathematicians, philosophy-of-science, set-theory

This question is about [Paul Benacerraf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Benacerraf), who worked on the philosophy of mathematics, and wrote the 1965 essay *What numbers could not be* (see: [Benacerraf's identification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benacerraf%27s_identification_problem)). He was at Princeton in the 1960s up to the end of the '00s, and presumably appears in at least one of the following two photos from 1968 and 1979 respectively.

[image: Princeton Philosophy department 1968]
[Source](https://philosophy.princeton.edu/about/sixties-snapshot)

[image: Princeton Philosophy department 1979]
[Source](https://philosophy.princeton.edu/about/seventies-snapshot)

My question is, can we identify Benacceraf in either of these photos? My purpose is to use a picture of him roughly contemporaneous with the essay in a seminar for undergraduate students.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site has [legends](https://philosophy.princeton.edu/gallery/1344) that identify him: 4th of back row in 1968, 3rd of front row in 1979.

Comment: Oh, excellent! I didn't find that...

Comment: All departments should have photos like that on their web sites!